Repeated measures ANOVA
I would like to seek help with a statistical analysis.
I am conducting a study on the learning outcomes of different teaching methods. My dataset includes student IDs, binary data on exam performance (good or bad), and the order in which the exam results occurred. I would like to understand if there are differences for example in learning outcomes between the first lesson and the third lesson.
I hope you could assist me in using SPSS to analyze this data. Please let me know the specific steps I should take, and how to interpret the analysis results. I thought I may use repeated measures ANOVA, but the data format of my data make me query myself on the analysis.
Your professional guidance would be invaluable for my research.

Code and program syntax requests are outside the scope of this forum, so I suggest you consult SPSS help pages for those. Do I understand correctly: you have students assigned to different teaching method groups, and then you measure each student's performance (as good or bad) in several sessions? So you have several (3?) good/bad measures for each participant?

This is a very detailed guide into running a RM-ANOVA in SPSS. SPSS is different from many other softwares wtr to RM-ANOVA in that you keep your data in short format, e.g. you'd have a separate column for each repeated measure. E.g. in your case (if I understood your design correctly as I wrote above) lesson1 would be one column, lesson2 another column etc. and each participant would only have one row in the dataframe.

However, if your outcome (dependent) variable is binary (good/bad), then a repeated-measures ANOVA is not suitable, you'll need to look into logistic regression.

The question is rather short on detail about the study design and the data, and after 2 days there hasn't been an update from the OP. I will attempt to answer, but by necessity, it is likely to be short on detail too.
So here are a few points to consider:

The outcome.

The question says

binary data on exam performance (good or bad)

and the goal of the research is to

understand if there are differences for example in learning outcomes between the first lesson and the third lesson.

This implies that the outcome variable is binary. As such, a logistic mixed effects regression model is indicated, and a repeated measures ANOVA is not applicable, since ANOVAs require a continuous dependent variable. Another possibility is Generalised Estimating Equations (GEE).

Mixed-effects Logistic Regression

Mixed effects models are models with fixed effects and random effects. Here, we have repeated measures within students/subjects, which will induce non-independency within subjects. A model with random intercepts can account for this dependency. In order to fit this kind of model in SPSS you need to have the data in long format - so that each row represents a single observation for a student at a specific lesson. It should include columns for student ID, lesson (a factor indicating lesson number), and Performance (binary outcome: 1 for good, 0 for bad). If you have other variables that can potentially explain the outcome, or are potential confounders, then you can include them too.
Programming questions are off topic here so I won't say much about that, other than to say you would go to Analyze > Mixed Models > Generalized Linear Models, set the Response (Performance); Lesson will be a fixed effect along with any other such as I mentioned in the previous paragraph; Strudent_ID will be the Random effect (random intercept); under Typeof Model, choose Binary logistic regression as the distribution and Logit as the link function.

Interpretation.

You will be interested in the estimates for Lesson. Usually, there will be a reference level for each categorical variable the estimate for which is part of the global intercept, and the estimates for the other levels of the variable are contrasts with respect to the reference level. So, for the research question, wanting to

understand if there are differences for example in learning outcomes between the first lesson and the third lesson.

The estimates for the other two levels of "Lesson" will tell you this.
